# QEMU builds fail on M1 Mac Mini with status : qemu-system-x86_64: qemu_mprotect__osdep: mprotect failed: Permission denied

Tags: qemu

QEMU builds fail on M1 Mac Mini with status : qemu-system-x86_64: qemu_mprotect__osdep: mprotect failed: Permission denied

The code is proper and my nasm compiler is functional

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression (bug) in MacOS 11.2. There is a workaround for it in newer QEMU; this will be in QEMU 6.1 (due out in a week or two). You need to either:

- not use MacOS 11.2
- persuade Apple to fix their bug
- build a newer QEMU source code that includes the workaround

QEMU bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1914849
QEMU upstream commit with the workaround: https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/commit/c118881ee607dcac